# find and sed to replace special characters

Tags: sed, find, replace

I'm looking for an easy way to rename many files on my Synology NAS. find and `sed` are available, but not `rename`.

I can get a list of these files and folders with

```
find . \( -type d -name "@*" -prune \) -o \( -name "**" \) -print
```

The above find statement displays all files containing a "/" character, in Synology bash substituted as "".

All the special charactes that I need to replace are:
 `/  \  :  ?  '  ’  ´  ’`

Depending on the platform and the file sharing protocol being used these characters will look differently, display differently or not at all or will cause different kind of problems.
I can find these characters within Synology bash with:
`` -name "**" -o -name '*\\*' -o -name "*:*" -o -name "*\?*" -o -name "*\'*" -o -name "*´*" -o -name "*`*" ``

How can I replace these characters in each of the files and directories it finds? I will start with the character "/".

Thanks a lot for any help!

Gary

Comment: The dot in`"*.*"` is not a printable one, I can't paste it in the terminal, are you sure that is the correct character?

Comment: Why not use `-exec` with `mv` and `sed` like you suggest yourself? This seems reasonable to me. Just try in a safe folder first before spreading it over the whole file structure. Also, better use `mv -i` to avoid file loss in case of a problem.

Comment: By "replace" you mean removing them or replacing for something else?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity if the OP can identify the set of files that match the character, we should assume it represents the right one even if we can't paste it

Comment: @roaima fair enough, I didn't know that you could have characters that can be pasted in the terminal (or google), although with unicode keyboard shortcut I could.

Comment: @Philippos — That’s exactly what I'm trying to do, but I'm lost. I have no idea how to make these things work together. For example, do I need to assign variables for the mv command, etc.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity: What you see as a dot is indeed a special character; in Synology bash this represents a "/" character in a file or folder name — that’s the reasn why I need to replace them with safer characters.

Comment: @GaryCzychi thanks for the aclaration. In your previous comment you mention the using o variables, could you [edit] the question if this is relevant information and a requirement for a solution?

Comment: "_The above find statement displays all files containing a "`/`" character_" how do you even get files containing `/`? Windows won't permit it (although to be fair, NTFS can), and it's embedded in UNIX/Linux/OSX kernels as a directory component separator so can't be used there either. Perhaps you mean something like [Division Slash `∕`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2215)?

Comment: The slash "/" is indeed very tricky. In Mac OS, you can use it, but it gets converted for the underlying BSD system. When you ls, it appears as ":".

Comment: I just tried with my QNAP and I can also use a "/" character in a file name (using AFP and a Mac). I don't know however, how QNAP treats this character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the `find` command matches the exact set of files you want to rename, and that you want to rename to "safe" filenames. Without knowing the precise character you've got in your filenames I can only offer suggestions, but here are two.

1. Remove the strange character. This presupposes the character can be handled natively by `bash` substitutions

   ```
    find . -depth \( -type d -name "@*" -prune \) -o \( -name "**" -execdir \
        bash -c 'echo "Processing $PWD"; for f; do echo mv -- "$f" "${f///}"; done' _ {} + \)
   ```
2. Keep only known characters. Make sure that `tr` has the set of characters you want to keep.

   ```
    find . -depth \( -type d -name "@*" -prune \) -o \( -name "**" -execdir \
        bash -c 'echo "Processing $PWD"; for f; do echo mv -- "$f" "$(tr -cd '[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]' <<<"$f")"; done' _ {} + \)
   ```

In both cases remove `echo` to convert the debug into an active statement.

Comment: roaima, you're right. The exact list of special characters is:

Comment: /   \   :   ?   '   ’   ´   ’   `   The difficulty is: Synology replaces some (not all) of them with its own special characters. So, in this bash command, "/" is for example "". Also, depending on the plattform and file sharing protocol the shares are accessed, these characters will display and behave differently and wreaking havoc in a different way. I will edit my question to include this information.

Comment: @GaryCzychi it sounds like the locale isn't set right on the Synology. I've not seen this problem with QNAPs but I have on a Samba share on a different Linux-based system. Fixing the locale fixed the character set, and no filenames then displayed with strange characters

Comment: I tried the first one and it works like a charm. I changed it so that it deosn't just deletes the "/", but replaces it with "·" — bash -c 'for f; do mv -- "$f" "${f///·}"; done' _ {} + \)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative using a for loop:

```bsh
# Option globstar activates the ** (search recursivelly).
# Option nullglob removes an * when it matches no file/dir.
$ shopt -s globstar nullglob
$ for i in **/*; do
    # if the name of the file matches the pattern
    # perform the `mv` command
    [[ "$(basename "$i")" =~ ^@.*$ ]] && \
      mv -- "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's;^@;;' -e 's;/@;/;')"
    [[ "$(basename "$i")" =~ ^**$ ]] && \
      mv -- "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed 's;;;')"
  done
```

Note: before executing moving/removing commands is a good idea to make a backup first.

Answer (score 0):

If your find command gives you desired result, you can pipe it to sed, and then from sed to bash (or redirect to file instead pipe to bash/ash):

```
find . \( -type d -name "@*" -prune \) -o \( -name "**" \) -print | sed -n 's/\(.*\)\(\)\(.*\)/mv '"'&'"' '"'\1\3'"'/p' | bash
```

- your find command will list your desired files and directories
- sed will go through all of your lines, substitute/remove special char and set every line for bash/ash (mv) execution.

Or you can redirect sed to file and bash/ash that file (bash list_of_files_and_dirs_to_be_renamed).
Test well on not imporant files/dirs before using it on real data.

Comment: That's going to break horribly on files that contain whitespace

Comment: You are right. It can be protected adding quotes around repeat sign &     
`sed -n 's/\(.*\)\(\)\(.*\)/mv "&" \1\3/p'`
I edited my post.

Comment: I think this will properly handle both, spaces and double quotes:

`sed -n 's/\(.*\)\(\)\(.*\)/mv '"'&'"' '"'\1\3'"'/p'`